# Calculate means

Tags: function, mean, libreoffice-calc

I have a column with 20000 numbers and I have to calculate the mean at intervals of 10 numbers.
So I must have the mean for the first ten numbers, from 1-10, the mean for the elements (11-20) and so on.

How can I write a function which can do this task?

Comment: You can add an additional column to it giving each 10 rows an identical ID and then create a pivottable with average as the function.

Comment: the problem is that I have said to have 100 elements just to do an example..in reality i have 20000 numbers, so i need some automatization of this calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, tested with LibreOffice Calc: Create your formula for the first sample (first ten values), and then copy it as many times as you need it.

For example:

1. To calculate the geometric mean of the first ten values (`A1:A10`),  put the following formula into `B5`:

> =GEOMEAN(A1:A10)

2. Select cells `B1:B10` (*! - not only `B5`*);
3. Drag the selection down as far as you need.

LibreOffice will copy the formula from `B5` to `B15`, `B25` and so on, adapting the attribute range to `B11:B20`, `B21:B30` and so on.

### EDIT:

To filter out the empty cells from Column `B`, just add a header row and apply a `AutoFilter` with condition `Not Empty`. The result will look like this:

[image: Mean - AutoFilter]

Comment: thank you; and then there is a way to extract the means in B5, B15 and so on automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Create two columns next to the columns you would like to average. In the first column you type 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc. Just make sure you copy this all the way to the last row (100 or 20k). Then in the second column you put the formula `=ceiling(column1samerow,1)`. The result is the following:

[image]

(example is from Excel as I do not have libreoffice; the `ceiling` function might be called slightly different e.g. `ceil`)

If you have the values you would like to average in column C then you create a pivottable with column B and C as data and you can proceed with that.